# Efficient way to filter files in directory based on time?

Tags: python

I wanted to get files from directory from 2018 or newer and matching regex so I did the following:

```
def list_files(directory, pattern):
    files = sorted(Path(directory).iterdir(), key=os.path.getmtime)
    files = [f for f in files
                if re.search(pattern, str(f), re.IGNORECASE) is not None and 
                    datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(directory/f)) >= datetime(2018,1,1)]
    return files
```

Is there a better way (Better Big Os) to go at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for the files that match the **regex** AND **created/modified after 2018**. Here you are doing a Linear Search - *which is **O(N)**.* *[N - Number of files in your directory]*

Since you have already `sorted` the list of files you can

- Use **Binary Search** to get the files that are modified/created in (or) after 2018. This will take **O(log N)**
- After applying Binary Search you will **only** have the files which are created/modified in (or) after 2018.
- And now since the number of files are reduced, you can apply your regex matching.

Effectively the Time taken to get the files after 2018 will be reduced from **O(N)** to **O(log N)**

And also the time taken for regex matching will be reduced as you are only applying this on the reduced list of files instead of all the files.